# Incorrect output of code after using pthreads

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I am working in some code trying to make it use threads, with little success. The code is as follows (using some online tuts)

(1) Create an array to save arguments to pass to each thread. 
(2) The struct where thread args are stored 
(3) Function each thread executes 
(4) Main, where I create each pthread and pass args. `end` and `begin` are dummy `i` and `i+1` just for testing purposes.

```
#include <pthread.h>
struct thread_data* thread_data_array;

struct thread_data{
   int  thread_id;
   int  begin;
   int  end;
};
void *proccessData(void *threadarg)
{
  struct thread_data *my_data = (struct thread_data *) threadarg;
  int id = my_data->thread_id;
  int start = my_data->begin;
  int end = my_data->end;
  printf("%s%d%s%d%s%d%s","Process: Id ",id," begin: ",start," end: ",end,"\n");

  // Init
  FILE* fileOut;
  // do stuff
  fileOut = fopen(someNameUsingId, "w");
  // more stuff
  fclose(fileOut);
}
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  int n_th = atoi(argv[1]);
  thread_data_array = malloc(n_th*sizeof(struct thread_data));
  pthread_t threads[n_th];
  int i;

  for (i=0; i<n_th; i++)
  {
    thread_data_array[i].thread_id = i;
    thread_data_array[i].begin = i;
    thread_data_array[i].end = i+1;
    pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, proccessData,(void *) &thread_data_array[i]);
  }
}
```

What I am getting: Sometimes nothing is printed, Sometimes some ids are printed twice. Files are not created (one in every 5 lets say, files are created, and are empty)

But using this in main works as I am expecting, id 1 from 0 to 1 is printed, id 2 from 1 to 2, and both files are created and have the right content

```
  thread_data_array[0].thread_id = 1;
  thread_data_array[0].begin = 0;
  thread_data_array[0].end = 1;
  proccessData((void *) &thread_data_array[0]);

  thread_data_array[1].thread_id = 2;
  thread_data_array[1].begin = 1;
  thread_data_array[1].end = 2;
  proccessData((void *) &thread_data_array[1]);
```

Can someone point out what am I doing wrong, and how to solve it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think `main` is ending before threads do, but can't figure out how to solve it

Comment: `pthread_join` will solve the issue, call it for each created thread in main

Comment: Is this necessary? Because I don't really need to join them, just that each one does its work

Comment: `pthread_join()` function is called to wait for the threads to complete. If main is done before threads are done, they will die before they finished their job

Comment: it works! Thanks. Post it as an answer and I will accept it. Could you please explain why is this necessary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pthread_join` will solve the issue, call it for each created thread in main. `pthread_join()` function is called to wait for the threads to complete. If main is done before threads are done, they will die before they finished their job.

Comment: since begginers as myself may see this, this is the code I added
`for (i=0; i<n_th; i++)
     {pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);}`

Answer (score 4):

Your `main` is terminating before the other threads. `main` is special, as returning from it is equivalent to call `exit`.

Either use `pthread_exit` to end `main` or use `pthread_join` to wait for the termination of the other threads.

Comment: since begginers as myself may see this, this is the code I added
`for (i=0; i<n_th; i++)
     {pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);}`